# Combine mutate and case_when in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I know how to use mutate with ifelse, when the new variable is binary, for example:

```
mutate(samecolor = ifelse(freqcolor == favcolor, "same", "different"))
```

But now I want to mutate a categorical variable into another categorical variable that is abbreviated in all values, something like:

```
mutate(fqclr = case_when(freqcolor == "bright red" ~ "br",
                         freqcolor == "light yellow" ~ "ly",
                         freqcolor == "emerald" ~ "ed",
                         TRUE ~ "wt"))
```

And this is not working. Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `case_when` annoyingly doesn't support non-standard eval yet, so to specify column names, you'll need `.$freqcolor` throughout. You should really make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by adding some data, though.

Comment: Thanks! That works like a spell~